# Exception/Report Timezone

Tags: magento-1, reports, exception

I'm a bit confused trying to read/compare Exception.log content and `/var/report/`

What is the timezone used ?

1. For Exception.log we have lines like the following one:
   `2014-06-05T12:57:49+00:00 ERR (3): ...`
2. For Reports we have files and file creation time.

So If I'm right the Exception logs uses UTC while the reports uses the Server time, am I right here ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure on this but i think that Exception timezone is based on php.ini file

which you can change something like

```
date.timezone = "Pacific/Auckland"
```

And reports you are right. That is why once timezone is changed, the lifetime statistics need to be refreshed.